# Is the user logged in? (restful-authentication)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, restful-authentication

I have used restful-authentication and I have "public" layout and a completely different "members" layout.  When someone visits my root (defaults to public) how can I check if they are logged in and redirect them to the member's section?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RestfulAuthentication provides some conditional methods/helpers including one called `logged_in?`. It returns true if the user is logged in.
Check out the `authenticated_system.rb` file for the list of all available methods.

Answer (score 1):

You could define a method like this in application_controller.rb:

```
private
def require_user
  # logic to check if session exists and redirect if not
end
```

Then add the following in your pages that require that the user be logged in:

```
before_filter :require_user
```

I'm not familiar with restful-auth so I don't know the exact check that would be required.

Good luck.